# Is the study of alternate universes important to Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, parallel-universe

During the TNG/DS9 and VOY time, was the study of alternate universes important to Starfleet?

Consider the TNG episode [Parallels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallels_(episode)). Worf comes across an anomaly that sends him to different parallel universes, and eventually the Enterprise comes across another Enterprise from a universe overrun by the Borg.

Won't Starfleet be curious as to how the Borg took over?

Obviously, we have potential problems:

- How exactly do you locate and access the universe you're looking for?
- Suppose you manage to open a wormhole, but to the wrong universe, how do you deal with a potential hostile species on the other side?
- What happens if you get trapped on the other side, how do you make it back?
- What happens if you end up in the right universe, but wrong time?

We know in Discovery S3, during the Temporal Wars, they discovered one alternate universe, the Kelvin universe. Sometime afterwards, time travel technology was prohibited, so the study of alternate universes probably stopped.

Despite the potential problems, is there anything in canon to suggest that Starfleet has a division to study alternate universes?

Comment: I don't remember anyone but Worf having any recollection about what happened to him

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - That maybe true, but remember the Enterprise has sensor and officer logs. Won't SF in some way figure out what happened and want to purse the study of alternate universes? They're already aware of one, the mirror universe.

Comment: I don't believe this was ever touched on in TNG, DS9 or Voyager. The USS Voyager had enough on their plate trying to navigate the Delta Quadrant and get back to Earth. The crew of DS9 had enough on their plate dealing with the Dominion, the Bajorans, the Cardassians and the Klingons. And TNG was very episodic; there were a lot of things that happened in a given episode, but were never mentioned again.

Comment: Maybe there's another department that does that.  After all, you have Starfleet for space, and DTI for time travel.  Hmmm, I sense another spin-off coming.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix He did. They even discussed it at a senior staff meeting.

Comment: They go from the final frontier to being Sliders….